# Downloading files?

Tags: downloads

How do you check the progress of currently downloading files from offline? I have gone to one of my favorite sites for download my music and cannot seem to check the progress of the downloading files. I downloaded files from the windows store and was not able to find it there. Please someone help.

Comment: Do you mean files downloaded with Internet Explorer, the Windows Store, or something else?